# How to troubleshoot a web-app that is crashing after running multiple hours

Tags: javascript, debugging, web-deployment

One of our web-apps (written with Scala.js) apparently crashes after running multiple hours (it is supposed to be running on a control cabinet without connection to the internet). I have been told that this application crushes after running roughly 8 hours with an `Aww snap, something went wrong displaying the webpage` - error message. Refreshing with F5 solves the problem.

For me that sounds like a 'simple' stack overflow error or something similar. Is there any good way of finding this error? This application is quite huge and I could not find the error by just looking at the code, so I have been wondering if there is any clever way of analyzing something like this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem using Google Chrome's developer console. Especially the "Performance Monitor" and the "Memory" tab helped me identifying the problem: indefinetly growing **detached DOM nodes**.

I managed to solve this issue by properly letting the DOM elements referenced in my Javascript code be garbace collected.

These pages helped me finding my problem:

[Fix Memory Problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/)

[Uncovering DOM Leaks](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks)